# What is &#39; and why does Google search replace it with apostrophe?

Tags: html, google-search, apostrophe

In what language does *and - hash - three - nine - semicolon* (`&#39;`) represent the apostrophe? I had some website data extracted in JSON format where some of the user comments had apostrophe which were replaced by `&#39;`.

So, what representation it is? I can not even google it as Google searches for apostrophe and not for *and - hash - three - nine - semicolon*.

Comment: You could have searched it without the semicolon, that would have worked.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

It's [HTML character references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#HTML_character_references) for encoding a character by its decimal code point

Look at the [ASCII table here](http://www.asciitable.com/) and you'll see that 39 (hex 0x27, octal 47) is the code for apostrophe

[image: ASCII table]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have still one query. How do you serch it in the google search bar so that it does not get replaced by apostrophe? So, that I could have got the links that you provided in the answer.

Comment: I don't need to search for it. A little html knowledge will help

Comment: That means there is no way to search for it unless we know what it is already.

Comment: No, you can guess from where it appears and read the documents for that. For example if it appears in URLs or HTML source codes then probably it's something related to HTML. Then read HTML documents and find for that

Comment: in cases that searching skills don't help, you can use a search engine for special characters like http://symbolhound.com/ in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685615/search-engine-for-special-characters?rq=1)

Comment: @RajeshSurana: Try searching for `&#39` without a semicolon.