# Unable to access child control in gridview from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

So here I am. I tried my best to do it on my own, I am a newbie to asp.net web-forms and I am beating my head for over a week on internet, read hundreds of posts but I totally failed in getting my issue fixed.
I am using a grid view I have Link Button which I want to validate with jQuery UI dialog button. First of all I tried to attach event handler from code behind i.e. **btnDelete_click(object sender, EventArgs e)** to be called on **Delete** button click of jQuery dialog, implemented from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28827196/how-to-call-a-codebehind-function-from-javascript-in-asp-net) I completely failed, I saw that, if it was an independent button , not in a parent container like grid-view etc, it works as done in above link but if it was in grid it keep saying that provided Id doesn't exist in current context. I tried everything I could:

**1)** Made button ClientIDMode = Static and tried to access it using ***document.getElementById('<%= btnDelete.ClientID%>').click();*** where btnDelete was ID of **Link Button**. Error I got **btnDelete doesnt exist in current context**.

**2)** Removed static option and Used ***document.getElementById('<%= gvDoctors.FindControl("<%= btnDelete.ClientID%>").click();***. Error I got was **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

**3)** With and without static ID mode I tried all approaches, also used **UniqueID** even I copied ID from **DOM Inspect Element** after right-clicking and inspecting Link Button but all in vein.

I then tried different approach I tired to run JavaScript from code behind using **Client.RegisterStartupScript**. I used StartupScript so that the script runs at the end of document just before closing body and form tag so that all elements are **created before getting referenced to**. Using This approach I was able to display jQuery pop-up but still old issue I have to call event handler of code behind like **btndelete_click(object sender EventArgs e)** from JavaScript and its not happening.

Here is my code:

**Web-Form**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDoctors" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvDoctors_RowDataBound">
  <columns>
           <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnUserID" runat="server" value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserID")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
             <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnDelete" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="test" OnClientClick="return stopASPOnClick()" OnClick="btnDelete_Click">Delete
               </asp:LinkButton>
              </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField> 

 </columns>
</asp:GridView> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var bootstrapButton = $.fn.button.noConflict();
    $.fn.bootstrapBtn = bootstrapButton;
});
function openDialog() {
    $('#dialog-delete').dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 150,
        width: 375,
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Delete: $("#dialog-delete").on('click', function (e) {
               document.getElementsById('<%= gvDoctors.FindControl("btnDelete").ClientID%>').click();
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }),
            Cancel: $("#dialog-delete").on('click', function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            })
        }
    });

   $('.test').click(function (e) {
        $('#dialog-delete').dialog('open');
    })
}


function stopASPOnClick() {
    return false;
}
</script>
```

So the **Question** being asked is how may I be able to get id of child control nested in a parent control like link button in grid, so that I can call its event handler from code behind, or it is not possible to retrieve same child control id as in server control to JavaScript(client side) and call their event handler like in the linked attached above. Thanks in advance.

**Note:-** I have also tried dialog script in document.Ready and without specifying them in function

Comment: [**`RowCommand`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) might be of help

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to add a jQuery dialog to the LinkButtons in your GridView.

```
<asp:LinkButton OnClientClick='<%# "return openDialog(this, &#39;Do you want to delete " + Eval("UserID") + "?&#39;)" %>' ID="deleteItem" runat="server">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
```

And the JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var confirmed = false;

    function openDialog(obj, msg) {
        var btn1 = "Confirm";
        var btn2 = "Cancel";
        $('<div />').html(msg).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            modal: true,
            position: {
                my: 'center',
                at: 'top+250',
                of: window
            },
            buttons: [
            {
                text: btn1,
                icons: {
                    primary: "ui-icon-check"
                },
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("destroy");
                    confirmed = true;
                    obj.click();
                }
            }, {
                text: btn2,
                icons: {
                    primary: "ui-icon-closethick"
                },
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            } ]
        });

        return confirmed;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: 1st of all thnx 4 looking into it, and its working to the extent that it opens  dialog when delete button is clicked in grid-view. If confirm is clicked it does a post-back to page load method . You did understand my **intention** but honestly it is not the answer to my question(even it works for me). One favor I ask of you, please guide me a little about syntax. I mean why does &#39 works and apostrophe doesn't and why I am getting a red underline at *?&#39* saying **_NewLine in constant_**, and what about **'?'** at closing &#39. Once again thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: `&#39` is a [HTML character reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29314258/5836671). HTML sees it as an apostrophe. It's needed because in a GridView you need the apostrophe for aspnet databinding `OnClientClick='<%#` so you cannot use it for javascript. If you look at the HTML of the aspx page you will see that `&#39` is often used. And the VS gives that error, I don't know why. Maybe a bug. That is why I usually fill that javascript content with a method from code behind (`getJavaScriptString(Eval("UserID").ToString())`)

Comment: The question mark is just to make a gramatically correct sentence. And to get the ID's of objects in a GridView, take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39986491/5836671).

Comment: OK I will implement your way of getting ID of nested control and I will see if I am able to call event handler function from code behind using that ID. Also you said, "I usually fill that javascript content, you mean  `+ Eval("UserID") +`  this portion by **that javascript content**. You mean that you write a custom method getJavaScriptString(string); like such in code behind and then you pass it arguments from within OnClientClick's function call? Instead of `+ Eval("UserID") +` please correct me if I am wrong.